# CSV file writing by using python?

Tags: python, csv

"ABC - PQR - ""$6,000 PY"" - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18"

"LMN - OPQ, XYZ - ""A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR""

I have above strings.

```
str=["ABC - PQR - ""$6,000 PY"" - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18", "LMN - OPQ, XYZ - ""A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR""]

with open('abc.csv', 'wb') as file:
    for str1 in str:
            file.write('\"' + str1 + '\"\n')
        file.close()
```

I have to write these strings in csv file by using python.
I am getting these strings in seperate columns.
How can I get these string in one column?

Comment: show us some code. what did you use?

Comment: import csv

str=[ "ABC - PQR - ""$6,000 PY"" - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18",
      "LMN - OPQ, XYZ - A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR"]

with open('abc.csv', 'wb') as file:
    for str1 in str :
        file.write('\"' + str1 + '\"\n')
    
    file.close()

Comment: Edit your question and put the code in it (instead of in a comment). Use the `{}` button to mark it as code so that it doesn't reflow. Otherwise it's very hard for us to see what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is still not clear, so I'm guessing to give you to give you a better mean to qualify your question

Correcting your code (you have one `"` too much at the end of your list and also the `f.close()` you don't need):

```
str=["ABC - PQR - ""$6,000 PY"" - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18", "LMN - OPQ, XYZ - ""A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR"]

with open('abc.csv', 'wb') as file:
    for str1 in str:
        file.write('\"' + str1 + '\"\n')
```

this outputs this:

```
"ABC - PQR - $6,000 PY - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18"
"LMN - OPQ, XYZ - A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR"
```

I guess the problem you have is that you forgot to put commas (`,`) between your strings. If you just put a space, python concatenates the two strings together as one string. So if you assign `str` like this:

```
str=["ABC - PQR - ", "$6,000 PY", " - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18", "LMN - OPQ, XYZ - ", "A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR"]
```

You get:

```
"ABC - PQR - "
"$6,000 PY"
" - 02/23/17 - 01/31/18"
"LMN - OPQ, XYZ - "
"A: 432 XYZ, LMN, PQR"
```

Is this what you want?